# Reseting Radio Buttons in Xamarin Forms 5

Tags: xamarin.forms, radio-button, reset

I am trying to create a Trivia App.  I have some very basic Xamarin Form code implementing a Radio Button.  The buttons work fine (ie a selection is registered and processed properly).  The issue is that after the first question is answered, the radio button selection persists when the second question is displayed.  Is there a way to reset the radio buttons between questions so that they are all not selected?

Here is the basic xaml code and the code behind:

Xaml:

```
                 <StackLayout Margin="20">
                     <RadioButton x:Name="Option0" CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged" IsTabStop="False" IsChecked="False"></RadioButton>
                     <RadioButton x:Name="Option1" CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged" IsTabStop="False" IsChecked="False"></RadioButton>
                     <RadioButton x:Name="Option2" CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged" IsTabStop="False" IsChecked="False"></RadioButton>
                     <RadioButton x:Name="Option3" CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged" IsTabStop="False" IsChecked="False"></RadioButton>
                 </StackLayout>
```

Code behind:  (Note: getQuestion() has the logic to display the next question so I have not included it here and I suspect something needs to be done at // do something to reset the radio button but I am not sure what to do)

```
    void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.CheckedChangedEventArgs e)  // sender is of class System.Object and must be converted in the proper type
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("\nRadio Button Clicked");
        Debug.WriteLine("sender: " + sender);
        Debug.WriteLine("e: " + e);

        var s = sender;
        var radioEvent = e;

        // converts sender to Radio Button type
        var radioButton = (RadioButton)sender;
        // Once in Radio Button type now you can see and use content
        string contentString = radioButton.Content.ToString();
        Debug.WriteLine("contentString: " + contentString);

        if (radioButton.IsChecked == true)
        {

            if (contentString == Movie.Text)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Correct", "You're Good!", "OK");
                Debug.WriteLine("Correct Answer");             
                ans_correct = ans_correct + 1;
                // do something to reset the radio button
                getQuestion();

            }
            else
            {
                DisplayAlert("Whoops", "Wrong Agian!", "OK");
                Debug.WriteLine("Wrong Answer");
                ans_wrong = ans_wrong + 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - I guess I just had to post the question to find the answer.

It turns out all I needed to do was put

```
radioButton.IsChecked = false;
```

where I had my comment

```
// do something to reset the radio button
```